# Reset location open wheater maps api

Tags: javascript, json, api, openweathermap

I'm trying to add button to reset location in this example: https://codepen.io/sinapsis7/pen/XKvdzr But I don't know how I can empty json results after click on reset button:

```
<div id="remove-location">
    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
</div>
```

With jquery:

```
$('#reset-location').on("click", function(){
    this.res = "";
});
```

Does somebody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing it this way!!
Anyways, try: `this.res = {}` instead, since res in your code is an object not a string.
Tip: learn to use const and let instead of var.
Otherwise your app looks cool.

Comment: Hello, for me was big mistake for doing like that (with shortcuts) instead of coding from beginnning with Vue.js like I know. Solution was: location = " ";. Thanks for help!